# How to move by one character without highlighting in Vimium?

Tags: google-chrome, vimium

In Vimium, when I want to copy-paste text, I search the string with `/mystring ENTER`. Then I go into visual mode with `v`, where I can move around with h,j,k,l keys. However, when the search ends up at the middle of a string, I'm in trouble, because I want to copy the whole string, and the copying starts from the middle of the string.

How can I move left to the beginning of the string, without highlighting the beginning of the word?

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on https://superuser.com

Comment: You're right. Maybe we could migrate it?

Comment: I don't have the necessary amount of reputation to do it myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you go into visual mode with `v`, use `c` to enter caret mode. That mode allows you to move without highlighting. After you've moved to the correct position, press `v` again, and continue editing in visual mode.

Additionally, if you want to copy whole words, then while in visual mode, you could use `w`. That highlights an entire word. And if you press it more than once, you get more than one word.